# How do I source an external script in /etc/sysconfig/httpd?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd

Let's say I have set EnvironmentFile in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` as follows:

```shell
…
[Service]
..
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

I then put the following in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`:

```shell
DEV_NAME="FOO"
```

When I restart httpd, I see the variable `DEV_NAME` under "Environment" in `phpinfo()`. It's all working as expected so far!

However, if I update `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` to contain the following:

```shell
. /etc/profile.d/www.sh
```

And `/etc/profile.d/www.sh` contains the following:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

export DEV_NAME="BAR"
```

I don't see the variable `DEV_NAME` in `phpinfo();`. I've tried moving `www.sh` to a different location, ensured SELinux context is updated (even though it is not enforced), and tried changing file ownership to `apache` user and group. None of that has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you don't. You can only source Bash scripts *from within* a Bash script, whereas **the file loaded by EnvironmentFile is not a script** thus it cannot source anything or do any script-like operations.

(Unlike traditional /etc/init.d or /etc/rc.d definitions, which were just Bash scripts from the beginning, the systemd .service unit itself is not a script at all – it's a declarative config file.)

Comment: Interesting. So where can one source a script for apache on EL systems? In Debian-based systems one can use /etc/apache2/envvars and /etc/sysconfig/httpd is suggested as the equivalent but it clearly isn't based on your explanation.

Comment: What do you need a script _for_?

Comment: I need a script because I need to dynamically set environment variables by pulling them from aws secrets or parameter store (similar to what is discussed in this article: https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c).

Comment: In that case use ExecStartPre= to generate a file for use with EnvironmentFile.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best solution I’ve found so far. I overrode ExecStartPre and EnvironmentFile in a service drop-in for apache. In ExecStartPre, I stored the output of the external script into a file that EnvironmentFile could use. Then used ExecStartPost to delete the file so its contents are not sitting on the filesystem.